# Stop Nuget from adding the relative path to the .csproj file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I have followed the recommendations of several posts found here on stack overflow regarding the creation/modification of the "nuget.config" file (next to the solution). It seems to be SEMI-working for me when trying to set my default location for my "Packages" folder.

See below for my "nuget.config" file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

   <config>
     <add key="repositoryPath" value="$(SolutionDir)\packages" />
   </config>

</configuration>
```

and this is what ends up being put into the .csproj file when a nuget package is newly added...

```
<HintPath>..\..\..\$(SolutionDir)\packages\SomeNugetPackage.1.1.1.0\lib\SomeNugetPackage.dll</HintPath>
```

It appears that the 'nuget.config' is being utilized, as it does inject my `$(SolutionDir)\packages` portion. It just adds relative pathing beforehand which breaks it! Is there any way that I can stop the `..\..\..\` portion of that from being added? I do not want any relative pathing in place.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I often open csproj in Notepad and edit the paths.

Comment: Yes, but this is not a viable long-term solution for me. I have been doing the same, I am trying to have it default to the correct location so that I don't have to do that anymore.

Comment: Then you need to complain to Microsoft

Comment: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/8233

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way that I can stop the ......\ portion of that from
> being added? I do not want any relative pathing in place.

**I am afraid that you cannot get what you want so far.**

The  `hintpath` will always use the relative path by default through the nuget mechanism. I am sorry that this is a nuget mechanism and we are unable to modify that nuget mechanism.

**No matter** how you set the value of the `repositoryPath`, even if it is an absolute path address such as `c:\test\packages`, it locates the value of the `repositoryPath` according to the current `xxx.csproj` address, and then assigns the relative path to each nuget package's **hintpath** when you install the nuget package.

**So in the current situation, we cannot use absolute path for hintpath.**

**Also**, `$(SolutionDir)` is identified by `csproj` file rather than `nuget.config`, so it will lose efficacy.

**Besides**, if you still want this, I think you should [suggest a feature on our DC Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=8). And the team will consider your idea carefully. When you finish it, you can share the link here and anyone including us will vote it so that it will get more attention from **Microsoft**.

All of these will help you get the results you want as soon as possible.

**Before doing this,please make a backup of your project.**

As a suggestion, you could use [PackageReference Nuget manage  format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files). It will reference the packages from global cache directly(c:\users\current user.nuget\packages) by default. And it will not involve any relative path and you do not have to worry about the hintpath.

Just right click on the `packages.config` file-->click `migrate packages.config to packagesreference`.

**And** if it does not meet your requirments,you could ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to put the source code under another drive; For example I will put the source code under D: drive and the packages folder under C: drive.